# Configure WEB-INF/jsp as base folder for all jsp pages in struts2

Tags: struts2

Here is the problem. In every action I map in `struts.xml`, I have always to point on JSP page using path as shown below:

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/cabinet.jsp
```

and so on.

If there is way to configure, say `package name="base"` in `struts.xml` to point on `WEB-INF/jsp` folder, as folder where struts should search for pages assigned in result tag?
Later on I can extend other packages from base and use as default JSP resources folder.

I did try use

```
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />
```

but there are no success,  if line above exists in `struts.xml` or doesn't. Struts still look for pages in base `WebContent` folder

Comment: If you are using convention plugin for your mappings why do you need to do so in xml?

Comment: as I mention in discussion with Andres below, I didnt find way to make it without convention plugin. I only found way to assign search path of jsp files for struts in conjunction with struts convention plugin. If u know way to make it with pure xml struts configuration I am happy to hear it.

Comment: if you are using convention plugin forget about xml configuration, it's only used to set the global settings to your struts application and in most cases should be abstract.

Comment: This is good question, but you can't modify configuration at runtime, thus you have to build your own config provider (that's what the convention plugin does) or build results on the fly, that might be not the best solution including a convention plugin.

Comment: @simar Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash at the end:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
```

and ensure you are specifying the result location without an initial slash:

Wrong:

```
@Results({
       @Result(name="success" , location="/success.jsp"),
       @Result(name="input"   , location="/index.jsp")
})
```

Right:

```
@Results({
       @Result(name="success" , location="success.jsp"),
       @Result(name="input"   , location="index.jsp")
})
```

Comment: didnot help. To clerify: to use convention plugin in struts(which gives ability to use result path constant) presence of struts convention library in the classpath is enought?

Comment: It should work, something is broken elsewhere :/ Are you successfully using the Convention plugin (by using annotations instead of struts.xml config) ? Ensure you are specifying the page without the slash in the result location definition

Comment: last question. Is this constant work only in case of using annotations? because i prefer xml. It is much easier for me to manipulate with xml without recompile code. XML, is just a personal preference.

Comment: Convention came to replace XML... why using Convention if you want to stick to the old XML way ? Convention offers annotations, "zero-config", package scan and so on. Lots of the features doesn't even need to be coded or configured: eg. if you write a class inside a package called "action", it will be published as action, with no need to declare it. I liked xml too... before discovering what convention can do. It is not just annotations instead of xml...

Comment: BTW now is clear that your problem was related to not using the convention plugin... in XML you always have to define the full path 
AFAIK.

Comment: I want actually to force struts search jsp files in WEB-INF/jsp folder. If I could find way to make it using pure xml that will great. I assume that since constant "struts.convention.result.path" startsWith struts.convention so convention lib should be in classpath. It is unclear in documentation, does it needs some configuration or not. But still I cant force struts to search jsp files in WEB-INF/jsp folder. :)